# MySQL - How can I do a conditional WHERE and OR clause Query?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

### Problem 1:

I need to add a field in a `WHERE` clause with a condition in my stored procedure, so what is the right syntax for the below query in `CASE` condition?

### Problem 2:

OR condition is giving me all records with values `0,1,2,3,4` for below condition (I need `tqm.is_imp = 1` if not found then `tqm.is_imp IN (0,2,3,4))`. What should I do? Please help.

```
tqm.is_imp = 1 OR tqm.is_imp IN (0,2,3,4)
```

My Query:

```
 SELECT tqm.id INTO selectedQuestionNumber
    FROM tc_question_master tqm
    INNER JOIN tc_question_mapping tqmap ON tqmap.tc_question_id = tqm.id
    WHERE tqmap.syllabus_chapter_details_id IN (SELECT cms_id from topic where chapter_id IN (SELECT id from MyChapters))
    AND tqm.marks = CurMark
CASE WHEN CurQuestionType > 0 THEN
    AND tqm.question_type = CurQuestionType
END
    AND (tqm.level_of_question = 'Easy' OR tqm.level_of_question
    IN ('Moderate','Difficult','Very difficult'))
    AND (tqm.is_imp = 1 OR tqm.is_imp IN (0,2,3,4))
    AND tqm.id NOT IN (SELECT q.question_id FROM QBDetails q)
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Good thing you are using stored procedures? do you have any knowledge on how to put your query into a `sp_executesql` function

Comment: No i don't know that but if it will solve my issue i will go through it. @Mr. J

Comment: it will! and it does work miracles. here is a link as your headsup

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e4f12c92-de68-4bcc-af0c-9dba97325c2e/spexecutesql-rowcount?forum=transactsql

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @N.S This question is attracting sqlserver comments,  Before you go down the sqlserver road SQLserver and mysql are different animals is this question tagged correctly?

Comment: that query does not compute... at all ("*computer says no*")

Comment: @Used_By_Already , Yes! i konw but i want to know right syntax for that.

Comment: the case expression is rubbish, it follows a column name with no conjunction, it's a mess. You want my best guess? that's all it will be

Comment: @Used_By_Already Thanks for comment. Suggest me some suggestion if you can share. the query is example to express my issue by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The upper part is just a reformat, but lower as you approach the logic that was a case expression, most of that is pure guess.

```
SELECT
      tqm.id INTO selectedQuestionNumber
FROM tc_question_master tqm
INNER JOIN tc_question_mapping tqmap ON tqmap.tc_question_id = tqm.id
WHERE tqmap.syllabus_chapter_details_id IN (
      SELECT
            cms_id
      FROM topic
      WHERE chapter_id IN (
            SELECT
                  id
            FROM MyChapters
      )
)
AND (
     tqm.level_of_question = 'Easy'
  OR tqm.level_of_question IN ('Moderate', 'Difficult', 'Very difficult')
    )
AND (
    tqm.is_imp = 1
 OR tqm.is_imp IN (0, 2, 3, 4)
    )
AND tqm.id NOT IN (
      SELECT
            q.question_id
      FROM QBDetails q
)

    ## now it is really vague 
    AND (
         tqm.marks = CurMark
      OR 
        (CurQuestionType > 0 AND tqm.question_type = CurQuestionType)
        )
    ## end of guesswork

ORDER BY
      RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```